# Offline Map in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, offline-caching, mktileoverlay

I have a big need to do an offline map for my app, as it is made mostly for Thailand, where internet connection is often hard to come by.  I am using OpenStreetMap right now for my `MKTileOverlay` but am having issues implementing it for offline use.  I have found a tutorial that says to subclass MKTileOverlay.  So, in my ViewController where the map is I have:

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  15.8700320, .longitude =  100.9925410};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  3, .longitudeDelta =  3};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
[mapView setRegion:region];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Map";
    NSString *template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
    self.overlay = [[XXTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
    self.overlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
    [mapView addOverlay:self.overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];


}
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id)overlay {

        return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];

}
```

In my subclass of MKTileOverlay, I have:

```
- (NSURL *)URLForTilePath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{%ld}/{%ld}/{%ld}.png", (long)path.z, (long)path.x, (long)path.y]];
}

- (void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path
                result:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error))result
{
    if (!result) {
        return;
    }
    NSData *cachedData = [self.cache objectForKey:[self URLForTilePath:path]];
    if (cachedData) {
        result(cachedData, nil);
    } else {
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self URLForTilePath:path]];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:self.operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            result(data, connectionError);
        }];
    }
}
```

The issue is that NOTHING gets loaded at all, unless I comment out the code in the subclass.  Where am I messing up?

Comment: You need to store all of the tiles locally.

Comment: @rmaddy I figured it was something like that.  Do you know how I could go about that?

Comment: @rmaddy I found tutorial at http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/ that deals a little with subclassing the MKTileOverlay, but I am still having issues with it.  Can you maybe help in chat?

Comment: @rmaddy check post for updates, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also interested in loading the map in offline mode.

1. First of all I downloaded the tiles into my local system (computer) with the help of **gmapcatcher**.

   You can get some information about the [gmapcatcher here](https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/). And you can [download this application here](https://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/downloads/list).

   One more important thing if you want to download the files **check offline**  and there are many ways that can save the files. For this scenario select **OSM** in setting window (located to the left side where you will specify the path to download in the setting window)
2. Simply add that created tiles folder to the project.
3. And I don' know objective-c so I am implementing in the swift and I posted that code only.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.mapView.delegate = self

        let baseURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL.absoluteString
        let urlTemplate = baseURL.stringByAppendingString("OSM_sat_tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
        //OSM_sat_tiles is the folder name which has the tiles.
        let layer = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: urlTemplate)
        layer.canReplaceMapContent = true
        self.mapView.addOverlay(layer)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKTileOverlay {
            let renderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay:overlay)
            renderer.alpha = 0.8
            return renderer
        }
        return MKTileOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
}
```

I will go brief on the code.

In the **viewDidLoad** delegate method I am creating *MKTileOverlay* by giving path of the tiles folder. Since I have placed in the project it will be in the bundle.

And in the **rendererForOverlay** delegate method I am returning the 
*MKTileOverlayRenderer*.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server which responds to your `http://<domain>/{z}/{x}/{y}/image.png` with an image or you must save the tiles in your app bundle using the path `/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}/image.png`.

Comment: Ok, where would I be able to download the tiles for Thailand?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JTileDownloader this software allows you to download tiles

Comment: That's a bad suggestion. Read the large warning in the wiki page. JTileDownloader doesn't respect OSM's tile usage policy.

Comment: I've used this tutorial to start off with http://nshipster.com/mktileoverlay-mkmapsnapshotter-mkdirections/ and it says you CAN do offline caching, but doesn't actually explain how to.